# background image in skewed div

Tags: html, css

having a problem here. I have a got my skewed div perfect but now I want the image to fit in it without tiling so if anyone can help that would be awesome.

I'm going for this:
[image]

And so far I have this:
[image]

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:500px;
background: url(../images/clouds.jpeg);
background-size:contain;
padding:10px;
margin-bottom:100px;
```

}

```
.box:after {
position:absolute;
content:'';
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
background:inherit;
background-size:contain;
transform-origin: top left;
transform:skewY(10deg);
z-index: -1;
```

}

Comment: what about to make white corner as separate skewed div overlaying nonskewed div with image background?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `background-size: cover` if you want the img to fill the entire container, and then use `background-repeat: no-repeat`to have one image.

Something like that should work:

```
.box {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  background: url(../images/clouds.jpeg);
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That image is not skewed..

```css
div{
display:inline-block;
 margin:10px;
 postion:relative;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:cyan;
}

div.covered{
background:
 linear-gradient(20deg,white,white,40px,transparent 40px,transparent),cyan;
}
```

```html
<div>
normal
</div>
<div class="covered">
covered
</div>
```

Bottom-left part can be done by covering image with white color with tilted linear gradient.

Comment: So I managed to get the result I wanted by using a clipping path instead. The next part will be overlaying the next image on top of the container

Comment: Close this question..upvote accept if any answer deserved..ask a new question..you will get many resources on placing some element on top of another.